# R package caret installed in R but failed to load in Rstudio-server

Tags: r, rstudio, r-caret, rstudio-server

I try to install the `caret` package and I do dev in RStudio server via the web.
The install goes well in terminal-R and I can load the package but when I go to RStudio it says its not there. And when I try to install it on RStudio server it gives me non-zero exit status so it fails...

Is there a way to make RStudio server to behave the same as the terminal R?

Comment: did you use an Ubuntu AMI on an EC2 instance ? If yes, did you use the free-tier t1.mirco instance?

Answer (score 0):

Compare the output of

```
 .libPaths()
```

between your two cases; also look into

```
 IP <- installed.packages()
```

and learn about the directory arguments to `install.packages()`.

Comment: > .libPaths()
[1] "/home/ruser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0"
[2] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                      
[4] "/usr/lib/R/library"

Comment: They are the same for rstudio server and terminal R

Answer (score 0):

It seems when I login to rstudio server with user ruser things just bail out when I do library("caret")

It works when I login as ubuntu.

Try not to that as super-user but not at least it works!